# com.android.server.PackageManagerServices and Android

Tags: android

I am trying to debug native code in my Android App development and I need to have com.android.server.PackageManagerServices in the device. I search the info for PackageManagerServices and can't find good info in the web.
My queries are
(1)Where to get com.android.server.PackageManagerServices?
(2)How to create this service available on the device?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. PackageManagerService is located at [/frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/pm/](http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java)
2. PackageManagerService  is a system service which gets started by [SystemServer.java](http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/SystemServer.java) at boot time and always keeps running. one need not to create another instance of it.

You can refer aosp source code at http://androidxref.com